# Concurrentlinkedqueue misses to add data in multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In the below code, in extremely rare case (3 in 1 billion executions of QueueThread object) it reaches the below mentioned if block and queue.size turned out be 7999. What could be the possible reason for the same.

```
 if(q.size()<batchsize){   
     System.out.println("queue size" +q.size());   
 }
```

Basically it fails to execute queue.add statement but executes all other statements in the thread.

The code snippet is as below.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;   
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;   
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;   
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;   

public class CLinkQueueTest {   


    public static final int itersize=100000;   
    public static final int batchsize=8000;   
    public static final int poolsize=100;   

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{   
        int j= 0;   
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolsize);   
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(poolsize);   
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();   
        String s ="abc";   

        while(j<itersize){   
            int k=0;   
            while(k<batchsize){   
                counter.decrementAndGet();   
                service.submit(new QueueThread(counter, q, s));   
                if(counter.get()<=0){   
                    Thread.sleep(5);   
                }   
                k++;   
            }   
            if(j%20 ==0){   
                System.out.println("Iteration no " + j);   
            }   
            while(counter.get() < poolsize){   
                //wait infinitely   
            }   
            if(q.size()<batchsize){   
                System.out.println("queue size" +q.size());   
            }   
            q.clear();   
            j++;               
        }   

        System.out.println("process complete");   
    }   


import java.util.Queue;   
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;   
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;   
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;   

public class QueueThread implements Callable<Boolean> {   

    private AtomicInteger ai;   
    private Queue<String> qu;   
    private String st;   

    public QueueThread(AtomicInteger i, Queue<String> q, String s){   
        ai = i;   
        qu = q;   
        st = s;        
    }   

    @Override  
    public Boolean call() {   
        try{   
            qu.add(st);            
        } catch(Throwable e){   
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }finally{   
            ai.incrementAndGet();   

        }   
        return true;   
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the one time that it registers one too few entries in the queue it is because the Executor has not finished its processing?

It is clear that every time `QueueThread.call()` is called the queue is added to and the `AtomicInteger` is incremented. All I can think is that one `call` has not been performed.

Perhaps you could be a little kinder to the system by using something like:

```
        while(counter.get() < poolsize){   
            //wait infinitely   
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5);
        }
```

but that's just my opinion.

Comment: But if one call is not is performed then the above while loop which you mentioned will never finish. This behaviour is extremely rare and not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue.size` method says:

Beware that, unlike in most collections, this method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these queues, determining the current number of elements requires an O(n) traversal. **Additionally, if elements are added or removed during execution of this method, the returned result may be inaccurate. Thus, this method is typically not very useful in concurrent applications.**

Comment: The `while(counter.get() < poolsize)` loop looks like it is supposed to wait until all activity is complete - thus supposedly avoiding this problem. Supposedly!

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue.size is definitely not a problem because it is called after the execution has completed.